# nlpaiDeleteRecord An nlobjSearchFilter contains an invalid operator, or is not in proper syntax: internalid

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to simply delete a record in NetSuite.  Here is my simple code:

```
nlapiDeleteRecord('customrecord66', 34020)
```

I try to do this via script, and in the Chrome developer window.  I keep getting an error that makes no sense:

```
An nlobjSearchFilter contains an invalid operator, or is not in proper syntax: internalid.
```

If I delete a record of the same type in the NetSuite interface, it will delete, or I'll at least get a meaningful message such as "There are dependent records".

Has anybody encountered this before?  Resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically this means there is a user event script or workflow running that doesn’t filter out events of type ‘delete’ but doesn’t handle them properly either.

Look for user event script deployments of the type of record you are trying to delete and inspect their code.

Comment: The error message was very misleading to say the least!  In Sandbox, I tested out your suggestion by temporarily undeploying all user event scripts attached to the custom record and I could successfully delete records!   Thanks!